# On a ubuntu 18.04 with two NICs, one NIC's ip always fails to ssh the connection

Tags: networking, ssh

There are two NICs in my VM.
The os of VM is 18.04.

The content of 01-network-manager-all.yaml is :

```
it@it51:~$ cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
      addresses: []
      optional: true
    enp0s31f6:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [172.16.11.39/23]
      gateway4: 172.16.10.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
```

The ip of enp3s0 NIC is 172.16.10.120

```
it@it51:~$ ifconfig
enp0s31f6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.11.39  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 172.16.11.255
        inet6 fe80::c600:adff:fe38:7cc8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c4:00:ad:38:7c:c8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 649361  bytes 148866878 (148.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 284603  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 63476  bytes 6153022 (6.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xdf400000-df420000

enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.10.120  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 172.16.11.255
        inet6 fe80::c600:adff:fe38:7cc9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c4:00:ad:38:7c:c9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 460878  bytes 40248747 (40.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 284630  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2964  bytes 336067 (336.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xdf200000-df2fffff

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 329  bytes 29072 (29.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 329  bytes 29072 (29.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Now I can only connect to 172.16.11.39 via ssh, but I can't connect to the DHCP assigned ip 172.16.10.120. What is the reason for this and how should I fix it?

Comment: Guess it's because they're both in the same subnet but can't tell why that is. Had the same problem with LAN+WLAN in same subnet.

Comment: @mawa，Do you mean how the problem won't happen if the two ip's are not on the same subnet? What is the rationale for this problem?

Comment: Just tried it in a VM. I guess it's because of the routing table which linux creates. The first device gets a metric of 100 and the second one gets metric 101 (check with "ip route" command ). So the first gets prioritized. I guess when you ssh the interface which gets DHCP addres (DHCP takes longer to assign IP than static) linux uses the other device for the response but your client expects response frome same IP. Not certain, just guesses

Comment: @mawa, thanks very much.